# Skeletons of n-categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

(Assuming choice) every 1-category is equivalent to its skeleton. In the skeleton category, the only invertible 1-morphisms are automorphisms. Can we do something similar for an n-category, obtaining a new category equivalent to it whose only invertible k-morphisms are automorphisms* for any k? Can we do it for $\infty$-categories?

A reference on this would be appreciated.

* (I actually don't know if the word automorphism is used for higher morphisms, but i mean in the sense of having the same domain and codomain and being invertible.)